# In Django I use request.POST and return JSONResponse but the url shows HttpResponse object error. I don't want to use render()

Tags: django, django-views, request

I'm using Ajax to submit a POST. In views.py I have the following:

```
def color(request):
    if(request.POST.get('mydata',False)):
        mylist= request.POST['mydata']
        mylist= mylist.split(",")
        request.session['var1'] = mylist[0]
        request.session['var2'] = mylist[1]
        return JsonResponse({'success':True})
```

In `urls.py` I defined `color`, so when I go to `localhost:8000/color` it shows error: "`didn't return an HttpResponse object`". I should use instead `return render(request,'app/color.html',{})` but I do not have a `color.html` file. I actually don't want to have one. All I want is to post a variable and use it as a session, so how can I avoid using render() and creating the html file? Thanks

**EDIT**: add ajax

```
list=['black','white']
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '/color/',
       data: {
         'mydata': list.join(","),
         'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
       },
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (data) {
         alert("it worked!");
       },
       error: function (data) {
         alert("it did not work");
       }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that all the code of your view? If so then the error is because you aren't returning anything if your `request.POST.get('mydata',False)` if-statement returns `False`. You need a final return, like this:

```py
def color(request):
    if(request.POST.get('mydata',False)):
        mylist= request.POST['mydata']
        mylist= mylist.split(",")
        request.session['var1'] = mylist[0]
        request.session['var2'] = mylist[1]
        return JsonResponse({'success':True})
    return JsonResponse({'success':False}) # a response is now always returned
```

**Edit** - for some reason the request.POST.get() is not working:

```py
def color(request):
    my_data = request.POST.get('mydata', False)
    if not my_data:
        return JsonResponse({'success':False})

    mylist= request.POST['mydata']
    mylist= mylist.split(",")
    request.session['var1'] = mylist[0]
    request.session['var2'] = mylist[1]
    return JsonResponse({'success':True})
```

Comment: Is it possible to return `success: False` only when `'mydata'` is not found. Because even if I do an if/else, the output is always `success: False` when `'mydata'` exists and when it doesn't :/, I can't print `success:True` at all in `/color/`. Why?

Comment: It should evaluate as success if `mydata` exists, I would add a print statement to check that

Comment: I do `print(request.POST.get('mydata'))` and it does print the string value but `localhost:8000/color/` keeps showing `success: False`. I don't know why it doesn't change

Comment: See my edit - extract the request.POST into a variable and check if it's false

Comment: Oh no it keeps showing `success: False`. It is so odd because if I do `print('my data:' + my_data)`, I get the string in the terminal but in `localhost:8000/color` it says (removing the success False line): `can only concatenate str (not "bool") to str` so although I correctly get the string and create the session, for `/color/` --> `my_data` is boolean :/.

Comment: I added the Ajax call in case it may help you to understand the problem. Thanks for your time

Comment: Are you just navigating to `/color/`? If so then there isn't any `request.POST` passed to it. Also, your AJAX code doesn't do anything with the response anyway. It would also always say 'it worked!' because it just checks for a successful response (i.e. HTTP 200), not the actual content of the response

Comment: how can I fix it? I would like `/color/` to be updated according to the `request.POST`. Yes the Ajax code just tells me if it was submitted, that's why I wanted the `views.py` `JSONResponse` to update the info in `/color/` (like a double check...Ajax checks that it was submitted, and `/color/` checks that the value was properly set. Maybe I'm making it too complicated and there is a simpler way to have a solid output that shows that all is fine. Thanks for the help